# reached the maximum partitions on my virtual machine

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-machines, partition

I have a virtual machine and I extended the size since I needed more space. Here is what I have and the message I am getting:

[image]

I was reading up and I saw some references to `diskpart.exe` and it gave me the following:

```
DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary             40 GB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Primary             20 GB    40 GB
  Partition 3    Primary             20 GB    60 GB
  Partition 0    Extended            40 GB    80 GB
  Partition 4    Logical             10 GB    80 GB
  Partition 5    Logical             10 GB    90 GB
  Partition 6    Logical             10 GB   100 GB
  Partition 7    Logical             10 GB   110 GB

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     Z                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
  Volume 1     E                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
  Volume 2     C                NTFS   Partition     40 GB  Healthy    System
  Volume 3     K   Salmon Rive  NTFS   Partition     20 GB  Healthy
  Volume 4     J   Taylor Gas   NTFS   Partition     20 GB  Healthy
  Volume 5     S   Suburban     NTFS   Partition     10 GB  Healthy
  Volume 6     D   DeClerk      NTFS   Partition     10 GB  Healthy
  Volume 7     H   Modern Hone  NTFS   Partition     10 GB  Healthy
  Volume 8     G   Modern Avoc  NTFS   Partition     10 GB  Healthy
```

I read that I could extend my logical drive and be able to create more partitions.

I'm lost at this point. I'm not sure which one I am go extend, if I can do so, or even what to do. I've not run into this problem before so it's outside my knowledge.

I need to create a handful more partitions on the 80 gb that I extended the size of the virtual machine by.

Can anyone give me a hand on what I am suppose to do at this point?

Comment: Why are you partitioning a single virtual disk rather than using separate virtual disks per volume?

Comment: And why are you creating a new partition when you do extend the disk, rather than just extending an existing file system?

Comment: @MDMarra that's a good question and I will check into that. I am new to hyperV but I will definitely go that route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple solution is to add more virtual disks, instead of expanding the drive and adding more partitions.

On top of allowing more partitions, this method allows you to move a single drive to a new VM (useful for building an updated server then just switching the data drives over.  It also reduces the risk of a corrupt virtual drive trashing all your data - only one virtual disk would need to be recovered.

On physical machines separate drives are usually preferred over partitions, but physical space and cost forces you to use partitions.  Virtual machines typically  have no such limitations, so use separate drives.

Of course this depends on the storage system behind the disks.  If each requires a LUN on a SAN for example you might have limitations.  But surely you can have at least 2 disks.

As an added bonus with most virtualization platforms you can easily add disks while the system is live.  Not always the case for expanding an existing disk.

On all my virtual machines each disk has only one partition (excluding small boot and utility partitions).  There is rarely any good reason to do it any other way.

Comment: As I was telling MDMarra, I'm new to HyperV and just learned how to do this with the help of your post and other posts. I am in the process of converting them now. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 3):

Using standard fdisk layout, you do have the maximum number of partitions: 3 primary and 4 extended.  What you would need to do is format the entire virtual disk using GPT partitioning which essentially allows unlimited number of partitions (practically through I think that the number is 64).  Windows can handle this format.

So my guess at this point is that you'll probably have to end up backing up everything, reformatting the virtual disk, repartitioning the disk, and then restoring the data.

Of course, if you end up regenerating and reformatting the virtual disk, then you can the fdisk partitioning scheme and properly size the partitions.

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is right or wrong but I don't like it either way :P